# Information regarding libjawt.so GetComponent on linux

Tags: linux, jawt

I am trying to find out what exactly the second argument of GetComponent method of libjawt.so  expects in order to return the component. It would be very helpful if somebody could point me to documentation for this method.
Thanks

Comment: getComponent only takes one argument?

Comment: it takes two arugments ,  first JNIEnv* and second void*  ..I am trying to find what this second  argument [void*] is supposed to  be on a Linux OS.